# search value within all keys in a nested elasticsearch object

Tags: php, elasticsearch

I want to know if it is possible to search value in all array elements in a nested `Elasticsearch` object in one single query? See my situation next:

In `ElasticSearch` database I've configured a nested object on column `name`:

```
$set_index = [
    'index' => 'table',
    'body' => [
        'mappings' => [
            'table' => [
                '_source' => [
                    'enabled' => true
                ],
                'properties' => [
                    "name" => [ // name of column
                        "type" => "nested" 
                    ],
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
];
```

Then I insert following data (through `PHP`):

```
$data1 = array(
    'descripotion' => 'Row 1',
    'name' => [
        'en' => 'First name data',
        'ru' => 'Первое имя',
        'de' => 'Eins data',
        'it' => 'something else',
    ]
);

$data2 = array(
    'descripotion' => 'Row 2',
    'name' => [
        'en' => 'Second name data',
    ]
);
```

And then I query on this data using the `POST` method through `Postman` `Chrome` extension:

`POST http://localhost:9200/_search`

Body is:

```
{
    "query":{
        "nested": {
            "path": "name",
            "query": {
                "bool": {
                    "must": [
                            { "match": { "name.en": "First" }}
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is working perfectly. In above query - I am querying data based on `English` translation in column `name`.

So if I wanted to search using the `Russian` language, the code would have been following:

```
{ "match": { "name.ru": "First" }}
```

Now, what I want to do - is to query on all translations at the same time (there can be 1 to 100 languages provided). Something like:

```
{ "match": { "name.*": "First" }}
```

1. question - is That possible, using my current config? If not with current config, then how? I know that if I convert `name` column back to normal type (instead of `nested`) - then it becomes possible, as all translations are concentrated into a single `string` type value. But in that case - i am loosing the possibility to be selective! I want both :) *Preferably, without data duplication*.
2. question - if I am searching for all translations at the same time - is it possible to prioritize one language over another? So if word `data` is in 5 languages - I want the document which contained `English` search result - to be first in the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright,

After going through countless tutorials I have come to the conclusion that `ElasticSearch` can not work with `Associative arrays`. Instead - `Multidimensional arrays` shall be used.

Here is an example. Before:

```
$arr = array(
    'name' => [
        'en' => 'First name',
        'ru' => 'Первое имя',
    ]
);
```

Converted to multidimensional:

```
$arr = array(
    'name' => [ 
        [
            'lang' => 'en',
            'value' => 'First name data'
        ],
        [
            'lang' => 'ru',
            'value' => 'Первое имя'
        ]
    ]
);
```

Now, back to my questions. Ending `ElasticSearch` query looks like this:

```
{
    "query":{
        "nested": {
            "path": "name",
            "query": {
                "bool": {
                    "should": [
                            { "term": { "name.lang": "it" }}
                    ],
                    "must": [
                            { "match": { "name.value": "first" }}
                    ]

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answers:

- Answer to question 1 - remove `should` section from query above.
- Answer to question 2 - keep the `should` section. Set the preferred language code there.

And if we want to search by specific language then `should` should be set to `must`.